# Javascript evaluate string as a comparison operator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if it would be possible to compare an int `"1"` and a string `"!0"`, and make the outcome true.

For example:

```
//Comparing 0 and "0" works...
var myVariable = 0;
var checkVariable = "0";
if(myVariable == checkVariable)
{
   console.log('Works');
}

//Comparing 1 and "!0" doesn't work:
var myVariable = 1;
var checkVariable = "!0";
if(myVariable == checkVariable)
{
   //I would LIKE this to be true!
   console.log('This part doesn't work');
}
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

I am open to suggestions, and `"!=0"` would also be fine as well.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
Update:

So I'm trying eval now, and here are the results:

```
var myVariable = 20;
var checkVariable = "20";
eval(myVariable,checkVariable);
   //Returns "20", which is ok I guess, but it would be nice if it returned "true"

var myVariable = 21;
var checkVariable = "!20";
eval(myVariable,checkVariable);
   //Returns "21", which is ok, but it would be nice if it returned "true"

var myVariable = 21;
var checkVariable = "20";
eval(myVariable,checkVariable);
   //Returns "20", which is *wrong*
```

Also tried this in chrome's javascript console (@Ishita):

```
var myVariable = 21;
var checkVariable = "!20";
myVariable == eval(checkVariable);
   //Returns "false", which should be "true" :/
```

Comment: You'd have to evaluate the expression buried in your string with either your own parser/interpreter or by using `eval()`. There's no way to make the language do it implicitly.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell There is a better way to handle this problem

Comment: @CoryDanielson :( K I'll think of another way. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `eval` it's widely considered to be one of the worst parts of Javascript and isn't needed at all in this case. (see bottom of this answer for more info on that)

Something like this would be an appropriate solution:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/zQjyz/

First, setup a map of `checkVariables` and functions that implement the expected comparison. All these functions do is accept a number and return true/false based on the result of a comparison.

```
var checkFunctions = {
    "0":  function(num) { return parseFloat(num) === 0  },
    "!0": function(num) { return parseFloat(num) !== 0; }
};
```

Next, modify your if statements to fetch the proper `checkFunction` based on the `checkVariable` and pass the `myVariable` into that function.

```
//Comparing 0 and "0" works...
var myVariable = 0;
var checkVariable = "0";

if ( checkFunctions[checkVariable](myVariable) )
{
   console.log(myVariable + " equals zero");
}

//Comparing 1 and "!0" doesn't work:
var myVariable = 1;
var checkVariable = "!0";

if ( checkFunctions[checkVariable](myVariable) )
{
   console.log(myVariable + " does not equal zero.");
}
```

---

[Don't use eval needlessly!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

> eval() is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed
>   with the privileges of the caller. If you run eval() with a string
>   that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running
>   malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your
>   webpage / extension. More importantly, third party code can see the
>   scope in which eval() was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks
>   in ways of which the similar Function is not susceptible.
>
> eval() is also generally slower than the alternatives, since it has to
>   invoke the JS interpreter, while many other constructs are optimized
>   by modern JS engines.
>
> There are safe (and fast!) alternatives to eval() for common
>   use-cases.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for such a great answer! ^_^

Comment: I updated the checkFunctions to both use parseFloat, because `parseInt(0.99) === 0` would return true. `parseInt(0.99)` just throws out the decimals (doesn't do any rounding) and returns `0`

Answer (score 2):

You can use "eval" function to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Awesome! Just tried eval(myVariable,checkVariable) and it worked. That was easy, thanks! Edit: Wait, no there are problems, Updating my post now.

Comment: Just be careful - [eval() is evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
var a = 1;
var b = "!0"; 
if(a == eval(b))
{
   console.log(true);
} else {
console.log(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but "a == eval(b)" evaluated to false :(

Comment: Here is the live demonstration for you. it seems to work for me. I am curious to why as in it is not working for you. http://jsfiddle.net/77Xns/

Comment: Oh! Yeah that it weird! I tried it in chrome's javascript console, I'll try it in my actual code to see if it works

Comment: Actually, I tried in my chome's console too, and it worked. Wonder what we both did different?

Answer (score 1):

Parse the string into an integer using parseInt

```
if(parseInt("1")!=parseInt("0"))
{
 console.log('Try this');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to be able to have the "!=" in the second variable though :/